# Proving if two functions are injective, then so are their compostions.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

My question reads:

If $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ are injections, then $(g\circ f)$ is also an injection.

Here is my work: (updated with new answer)

Let $x,y \in\ A$ such that $(g\circ f)(x)$ $=$ $(g\circ f)(y)$. Then, by composition, $(g\circ f(x))=(g\circ f(y))$ and since $g$ is an injection, it follows that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then, because $f$ is an injection, we have that $x= y$, which proves that $(g\circ f)$ is also an injection.

Now is this correct?

Comment: I would just make a small set and show that there's only one path between the first and last sets used.

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid proof to me.  The definition of injective is $ \forall a,b, f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b $ (or its contrapostive) however you have proved $ \exists a, b f(a) \neq f(b) \implies a \neq b $

Comment: @QthePlatypus I see then I did not properly use the contrapositive?

Comment: The contrapostive is $\forall a,b . a \neq b \implies f(a) \neq f(b) $ you have to swap the order as well as not the entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks a little clunky

Given that $g,f$ are an injections

$g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \implies f(x) = f(y)\\
f(x) = f(y) \implies x=y\\
\therefore g\circ f(x) = g \circ f(y) \implies x=y $

Or you can use the contrapostive:

$x\ne y \implies f(x) \ne f(y) \implies g\circ f(x)\ne g\circ f(y)$

But you seem to be attacking form both end to meet in the middle and that is less clear.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that I was mixing up the definitions in there somewhere. Then I will rewrite this to see if it makes sense and update my answer.

Comment: Just one question, then can i still begin with x and y in A, only now i would say that x does not equal y?